# Old MacDonald Sum of total animals should be 44

Tags: python, sum, txt

My issue is that I can't get the total amount of animals from my animals.txt file

```
2 pig oink
3 duck quack
4 horse neigh
5 lamb baa
6 chickens cluck
7 dog woof
8 cat meow
9 cow moo
----------
44
```

to show 44 total animals in my python program. Below is what I have.

```
def write_verse(vfile,animals): #function to write the animals into a verse.txt file
    with open('animals.txt', 'r') as f:
        result = sum(map(int, vfile))
    count = 1
    for animal in animals:  #loop to iterate through all animals
        amount = animal[0]
        name = animal[1]
        noise = animal[2]
        format1 = f'Verse :{count}\n'   #formatting strings
        format2 = f'Old MacDonald had a farm\n'
        format3 = f'E-I-E-I-O\n'
        format4 = f'And on his farm he had {amount} {name}\'s\n'
        format5 = f'With a {noise} {noise} there\n'
        format6 = f'And a {noise} {noise} here\n'
        format7 = f'Here a {noise},there a {noise}\n'
        format8 = f'Everywhere a {noise} {noise}\n'
        string =str(format1+format2+format3+format4+format3+format5+format6+format7+format8+format2+format3)
        vfile.write(string+"\n")    
        print(string)
        count+=1
    vfile.write("Old MacDonald has a total of {0} animals".format(count-1))
    print(f"Old MacDonald had a total of {result} animals")


try:
    file = open('animals.txt','r')
except FileNotFoundError as a:
    print(a)
contents = file.readlines()

animals_list = []
for line in contents:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    animals_list.append(line.split(" "))

file.close()

try:
    vfile = open("verses.txt","w+")
except:
    pass
write_verse(vfile,animals_list)
vfile.close()
```

---

This is what happens when I run it  -

Verse :1
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 2 pig's
E-I-E-I-O
With a oink oink there
And a oink oink here
Here a oink,there a oink
Everywhere a oink oink
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Verse :2
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 3 duck's
E-I-E-I-O
With a quack quack there
And a quack quack here
Here a quack,there a quack
Everywhere a quack quack
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Verse :3
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 4 horse's
E-I-E-I-O
With a neigh neigh there
And a neigh neigh here
Here a neigh,there a neigh
Everywhere a neigh neigh
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Verse :4
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 5 lamb's
E-I-E-I-O
With a baa baa there
And a baa baa here
Here a baa,there a baa
Everywhere a baa baa
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Verse :5
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 6 chickens's
E-I-E-I-O
With a cluck cluck there
And a cluck cluck here
Here a cluck,there a cluck
Everywhere a cluck cluck
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Verse :6
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 7 dog's
E-I-E-I-O
With a woof woof there
And a woof woof here
Here a woof,there a woof
Everywhere a woof woof
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Verse :7
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 8 cat's
E-I-E-I-O
With a meow meow there
And a meow meow here
Here a meow,there a meow
Everywhere a meow meow
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Verse :8
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 9 cow's
E-I-E-I-O
With a moo moo there
And a moo moo here
Here a moo,there a moo
Everywhere a moo moo
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Old MacDonald had a total of 0 animals

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When you run your script, what happens?   Please include the actual output as well.

Comment: `result = sum(map(int, vfile))` I think you meant to use `f` here, not `vfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing `result`, but `result` isn't calculated correctly. There are kind of a lot of issues with your code, and somebody has already pointed out how to fix the problem. So instead, I'm going to make some suggestions for writing cleaner, more organized code which can make debugging issues much easier:

```py
# Use a template literal string formatted almost exactly as 'WYSIWYG'
VERSE = """
Verse: {verse}
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had {amount} {animal}s
With a {noise} {noise} here
And a {noise} {noise} there
Here a {noise} there a {noise}
Everywhere a {noise} {noise}
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
"""


# Separate helper function to read in your data
def read_file(path):
    data = []
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            amount, animal, noise = line.strip().split()
            data.append({"animal": animal, "noise": noise, "amount": int(amount)})
    return data


# Write any number of verses given a list of animals
def sing_old_macdonald(animals):
    song = ""
    total = 0
    for verse, animal in enumerate(animals, 1):
        song += VERSE.format(verse=verse, **animal)
        total += animal["amount"]
    return song, total


# Main script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    animals = read_file("animals.txt")
    song, total_animals = sing_old_macdonald(animals)
    print(song)
    print(f"Old MacDonald has {total_animals} animals on his farm")
```

Trimmed output:

```py
.
.
.

Verse: 8
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O
And on his farm he had 9 cows
With a moo moo here
And a moo moo there
Here a moo there a moo
Everywhere a moo moo
Old MacDonald had a farm
E-I-E-I-O

Old MacDonald has 44 animals on his farm
```

Comment: `write_verse` doesn't _write_ anything and would be more aptly named `format_verse`. Also why does it take keyword-only arguments? There's no need to do that. In fact, the `write_verse` function seems redundant since all it does is pass all its arguments to `str.format()`.

Comment: 1. I only mentioned it since you made your answer about writing _cleaner, more organized code._ Part of writing clean code is naming your functions for what they actually do. It's not pedantic to think that a function called `write_verse` writes something. 2. Maybe I'm misunderstanding why keyword-only args are needed, but I can't think of a way to screw up what gets input into the format string. What situation are you guarding against? I'd understand having to ensure all the keywords were given if you passed them directly to `VERSE`, but since you have a wrapper it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Ty for this, I am obviously just learning how to write but I apprecite everyone's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `vfile` variable is a file object pointing to an empty file (the one that you write the output to), so when you do `sum(map(int, vfile))`, it produces 0, as it is summing zero lines.

You already have the number of each animal in your `animals` variable, so to fix the problem you can replace this:

```
with open('animals.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = sum(map(int, vfile))
```

With this:

```
result = sum(int(animal[0]) for animal in animals)
```